# Ocaml graph : coloring graph with bfs

Tags: ocaml

graph coloring (BFS):
given a graph and a set of "colors", is of integers from 1 to N, assigning an integer to each vertex in a way that adjacent vertices are assigned different colors

can anyone help me do this project?

Answer (score 4):

Sure. Start from a vertex. Pick an uncolored vertex. Add it to a list of processed vertices. Color it with the smallest number different than the numbers of its neighbors, if it isn't greater than N. Otherwise delete vertices from the list until you meet a neighbor of the vertex which couldn't have a color assigned, and erase their colors. Assign the smallest free color to the vertex on which we stopped higher than the color it previously had. Continue.

ETA: this is depth-first-search though, not breadth-first-search :-( I still think that DFS is better than naive BFS for graph coloring.

Comment: thanks :D but I do not know ocaml just fine, could you help me step by step, maybe even with the code to be written
I use ocamlwin for edit the code, I do not understand is the difference as ocamlwin and Emacs ?

Comment: @user2532260 I suggest that you ask your teacher to help you get started.